# Is else...if statement in C equals to else { if }?

Tags: c, if-statement

My question:

Is this:

```c
if (...) {
  
} else if (...) {
  
}
```

Equal to this?

```
if (...) {
  
} else {
  if (...) {
    
  }
}
```

Indeed, I guess that in the two cases the result would be the same but is else..if a different statement in C ?

Comment: It's exactly the same thing.

Comment: That's correct.  C doesn't really recognize `else if` as its own entity.  It just treats it as an `else` whose statement happens to be another `if`.

Comment: Ok! That was quiet quick. Thank you :)

Comment: I like to draw truth table to understand these scenarios. Draw truth table for the two conditions (four permutations) and write which code block is executed. Then compare the results for these two scenarios.

Comment: If you would use a more readable indention style, it would become much more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are **almost** the same thing.

They are the same as a compiler would treat them exactly as they stand now.

However, they are not the same for development purposes. If additional code is inserted immediately after the end of the enclosed `if` statement, it will be grouped with that statement in the code with the braces around that `if` statement but not in the code without those braces. Issues like this are potential causes of bugs, so the difference may be significant.

Answer (score 3):

The C language has no feature called `else if`. That one is only obtained through coding style. Your example is 100% equivalent to this:

```
if (...) {
  
} 
else 
  if (...) {
  
  }
```

Where the second `if` is a single statement below `else`, so we can write it without `{}`.

Comment: And because of this we can amuse ourselves with `else maybe: if` and similar important constructs :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (...) {
  
} else if (...) {
  
}
```

is same as

```
if (...) {
  
} else {
  if (...) {
    
  }
}
```

---

but

```
if (...) {
  
} else if (...) {
  
}
```

is not same as

```
if (...) {
  
} else {
   ... // extra statements
  if (...) {
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the comments suggesting drawing truth table, logically equivalent programs aren't always the same in terms of the generated assembly (they will behave the same) but consider:

```
int main()
{ 
    int a = 1;
    if (a)
       if(a)
          return 0;
}
```

And

```
int main()
{ 
    int a = 1;
    if(a)
      return 0;
}
```

Compiling with no optimization `-O0`

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        je      .L2
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        je      .L2
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
.L3:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

---

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        je      .L2
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
.L3:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4ajevq

Comment: good answer only exception is compailer optimization

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
    if(...){
    } else{ 
        if(...){ ... }
    }
```

That would be the same as

```
if (...) {
  
} else if (...) {
  
}
```

As long as you keep the `else` statement empty except for the second if statement.

`else if` isn't technically its own statement. else if is literally an else statement and then an if statement.